# Grails - how to get object domain fields without GORM additional fields?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In order to have a validation on my domain class object, I need to get all the relevant fields that I need to have validation on.
The exact fields I need are those who I defined by myself in my domain class and not those who GORM did.

I need to know how can I get those fields ?
I mean, how to I get all the fields without 'id', 'version' and all other GORM generated fields. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

If you have a domain class like this:

```
// grails-app/domain/com/demo/Person.groovy
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    // notice that only firstName is constrained, not lastName
    static constraints = {        
        firstName matches: /[A-Z].*/
    }
}
```

You can interrogate the persistentProperties property to get a list of all persistent properties:

```
def person = new Person()
def personDomainClass = person.domainClass
// this will not include id and version...
def persistentPropertyNames = personDomainClass.persistentProperties*.name

assert persistentPropertyNames.size() == 2
assert 'firstName' in persistentPropertyNames
assert 'lastName' in persistentPropertyNames
```

If you wanted to do the same sort of thing but don't have an instance of the Person class to interrogate you can do something like this:

```
def personDomainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.demo.Person')
// this will not include id and version...
def persistentPropertyNames = personDomainClass.persistentProperties*.name

assert persistentPropertyNames.size() == 2
assert 'firstName' in persistentPropertyNames
assert 'lastName' in persistentPropertyNames
```

You could also get the keys out of the constraints Map:

```
// this will include both firstName and lastName,
// even though lastName is not listed in the constraints
// closure.  GORM has added lastName to make it non
// nullable by default.
// this will not include id and version...
def constrainedPropertyNames = Person.constraints.keySet()

assert constrainedPropertyNames.size() == 2
assert 'firstName' in constrainedPropertyNames
assert 'lastName' in constrainedPropertyNames
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Helped a lot!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `constraints` property on a domain class instance gives you a list of `ConstrainedProperty` objects representing the properties that are listed in the `constraints` block in the domain class, in the order they are listed (see the bottom of [this documentation page](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/constraints.html)).

```
static constraints = {
  prop2()
  prop1(nullable:true)
  prop3(blank:true)
}
```

So provided you have mentioned every property in the `constraints` block then you can use

```
myObj.constraints.collect { it.propertyName }
```

to get a list of the property names (in the above example you'd get `[prop2, prop1, prop3]`).

Comment: It's a good way. But what happens when some other developer adds a field and ignores the constraints list? I know that it his responsibility, but it still can make future bugs.

Comment: "The constraints property on a domain class instance gives you a list of ConstrainedProperty objects representing the properties that are listed in the constraints block".

I do not think that is correct.  I think the constraints property is going to be a Map where the keys in the map are the property names.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown that's not what the documentation says, though it may of course be out of date.

Comment: I was describing the way that the software behaves.  I have updated the docs to be consistent with that.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/0875c9b55050c6cb1f3cc462482dd4fae301c2fd.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks.  It's probably worth also making it explicit in the documentation that the iteration order of this map is guaranteed to match the order things are listed in the constraints block.

Comment: "It's probably worth also making it explicit in the documentation that the iteration order of this map is guaranteed to match the order things are listed in the constraints block.".  Why do you think it is guaranteed?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I was sure I'd read in the past that `constraints` was guaranteed to follow the order but that would have been quite a few versions ago, I admit.  Certainly it has been when I've tried it, and the code for `ConstrainedPropertyBuilder` builds a `LinkedHashMap`, but this behaviour may be accident rather than design which is fair enough.